# Why use Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake

I saw this question [What is the purpose of Rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669400/what-is-the-purpose-of-rake) but I still don't get it.

Why can't you just create a Ruby script in a file and run `ruby myscript.rb`?

What does using a Rake task let you do that regular ol' Ruby doesn't?

Comment: If you are using a rake the task as part of the rails project, you can leverage the rails framework in your rake task such as the ActiveRecord asset, Helpers etc.

Comment: @PackedUp Couldn't I just have the file include rails_helper or require the active support / active record gems?

Comment: If the Rake task is part of your rails project it is important to keep it dry and it becomes part of your deployment container. The controllers, models or helper don't require special requires. Your rake task will also not need any special requires as the frame work provides them by default.

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons. Rake has the following benefits:

- Users can specify tasks with prerequisites.
- A library of prepackaged tasks to make building rakefiles easier. For example, tasks for building tarballs and publishing to FTP or SSH sites. (Formerly tasks for building RDoc and Gems were included in rake but they're now available in RDoc and RubyGems respectively.)
- Supports parallel execution of tasks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about prerequisites? Do you mean like checking conditions? Ruby does that. What's different from having a Ruby file that builds tarballs and does publishing? And how would Rake tasks support parallel execution if Ruby is single threaded?

Comment: It's in rational.rdoc in the original documentation for rake if you've read it: http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rational_rdoc.html

Comment: How do any of the benefits you mentioned stand out as separate from Ruby? I'm still confused